# How to return a specific result from a list of results generated by a recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

I am using  a functionality where I have preferred to use recursion to solve that, I am getting my output from the recursion but my problem is that I want  a specific output from that list of output of the recursion.I Can not do that please help me I am giving what I have done so far

```
 public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "0";
    int count =3;
    aMethod(s,count);

}

private static void aMethod(String s,int count) {

    String t ="";
    String finalBinaryString ="";
    int iteration =0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

        char f = s.charAt(i);
        int tt = 1- Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f));
        t += String.valueOf(tt);
    }
    finalBinaryString = s+t;
    if(iteration<count)
    aMethod(finalBinaryString,--count);
    System.out.println(finalBinaryString);  
}

  }
```

The output I am getting is

```
   0110100110010110
  01101001
  0110
  01
```

I just want the largest one.Not the others.But I am not able to get it.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return finalBinaryString as a result of your recursion.

There is example:

```
public class Test {
    static String finalBinaryString ="";
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "0";
        int count =3;

        System.out.println(aMethod(s,count));

    }

    private static String aMethod(String s,int count) {

        String t ="";

        int iteration =0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

            char f = s.charAt(i);
            int tt = 1- Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f));
            t += String.valueOf(tt);
        }
        finalBinaryString = s+t;
        if(iteration<count)
            aMethod(finalBinaryString,--count);
        return finalBinaryString;
    }

}
```

Comment: is it working ?? please give me the longest string as a string output

Comment: I got compilation erro in System.out.println(aMethod(s,count)); line

Comment: if i am using your code it is returning me the first value

Comment: It is impossible, this code returns the longest value. May be you have some changes in your code, do you?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid having the `String` as static, then you can get the required result from the method this way (see the `if (iteration < count)` part).

```
 public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        String s = "0";
        int count = 3;

        System.out.println(aMethod(s, count));

    }

    private static String aMethod(final String s, int count) {

        String t = "";

        int iteration = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            char f = s.charAt(i);
            int tt = 1 - Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(f));
            t += String.valueOf(tt);
        }
        String finalBinaryString = s + t;

        if (iteration < count) {
            finalBinaryString = aMethod(finalBinaryString, --count);
        }

        return finalBinaryString;
    }

}
```

Comment: i can  return the value from  this recursion ??